# Azure pipelines command line: give confirmation

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

In one of my tasks in an Azure DevOps pipeline, I am trying to stop the IIS Server.
This can be achieved by calling the command `net stop WAS` in the command prompt. Doing this manually, it asks for a confirmation

[image]

Manually, I can just pres `Y` `ENTER`.
But how would i do this in an azure task command?
Simply adding a new line with `Y` does not work

[image]
[image]

**TLDR** how do I add a confirmation to an azure task command line command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In windows, you can run `net stop WAS /y` this will bypass any prompts that you are trying to pass with the option **Y**.